# Custom index was not found error in in Azure Paas Content Delivery

Tags: content-search, azure-search, index

My custom index "custom_index" was not found error is coming in Sitecore 8.2 on the Azure Paas CD environment.

But the same custom_index is accessible in the CM environment.

I'm using the Azure Search Service.
How do we resolve that? Are there any config changes required?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index needs to be configured in the indexes node. Probably that is done on CM but not on CD.

Check the config on CD for something like:

```
<contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
     <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
        <index id="your-index-name" type="..">
        ....
```

As mentioned I would assume you will find this on the CM but not on the CD. In that case, check the file where the custom index is configured and get that also available on the CD.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i am able to access from the cd.